# How to add an existing portlet to Web Content Display using Velocity templates

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I want to create a new page using `Web Content Display` with `Velocity Templates` and `Structures`.

On my page I would like to have multiple tabs and on each tab needs to be added programatically from a template of an existing portlet.

I know how to add an existing portlet to my theme `($theme.runtime("portlet_id"))` but I can't find a way to add the portlets to a velocity template since `$theme` object is not available in a Web Content Display template.

Can you please tell me if it is possible to add a portlet to a template?
If yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the runtime-portlet tag in the velocity templates:

```
<div id="portlet-inside-wc">
  <runtime-portlet name="portlet-id" instance="instanceID" queryString=""/>
</div>
```

Where name is the portlet ID, instance is the 4 letter unique (Alpha Numeric) word and Querystring can be portlet preferences.